# Ruby concatenation and interpolation to generically create instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

a method is intended to generically work with variable `klass` to create an instance variable from a string concatenation, then subsequently execute an operation (counter) on it

```
string = "@new_" + klass.to_s.downcase
string = string + 1
```

while the string is generated correctly `@new_office` the operation cannot be effected because an integer is being summed to a string.  The instance variable is already initialised & has to be incremented, not reset.

Other attempts via interpolation also generated errors

```
syntax error, unexpected string literal, expecting `end'
      @new_"#{klass.to_s.downcase}" = @new_"#{klass.to_s.downcase}" + 1

unexpected '=', expecting `end'
      "@new_#{klass.to_s.downcase}" = "@new_#{klass.to_s.downcase}" + 1

`@' without identifiers is not allowed as an instance variable name
      @"new_#{klass.to_s.downcase}" = @"new_#{klass.to_s.downcase}"
```

How should can instance variable be constructed via concatenation + interpolation?

Comment: While you can create instance variables dynamically via [`instance_variable_set`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Object.html#instance_variable_set-method), it's usually a bad design. If you need something generic, maybe use a hash to hold your counters, e.g. `@counters = Hash.new(0)` and increment it via `@counters[klass.to_s.downcase] += 1`

Answer (score 1):

you can use [instance_variable_set](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_set) and [instance_variable_get](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Object/instance_variable_get) to set and get dynamic instance variable

```rb
self.instance_variable_set("@new_#{klass.to_s.downcase}", instance_variable_get("@new_#{klass.to_s.downcase}") + 1)
```

Comment: Upvoting this answer as it does provide a method to do as the question asked.  However the comment by @Stefan is pertinent and the chosen path : it feels a lot cleaner and allows for clearer refactoring overall (there are more layers of complexity to the issue at hand.